# Swift - Can't change Font Style in UILabel

Tags: swift

I'm coding without storyboard. I'm adding UILabels into ViewControllers programmatically like below but somehow font style stays with the default. Can someone tell what the problem is with my codes? Thank you!

```
let label: UILabel = {

    let label = UILabel()

    label.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: 20)
    let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Text.", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black, NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)])

    // Letter spacing
    attributedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.kern, value: 1.5, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedText.length - 1))

    // Charactor spacing
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 4
        attributedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length))

    label.attributedText = attributedText

    return label

}()
```

Answer (score 3):

The font for the attributed text takes priority over the font for the label, itself. And you have explicitly defined your attributed text to use `UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)`.

I'd suggest either using your font for the attributed string:

```
let font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: 20)
let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Text.", attributes: [.foregroundColor: UIColor.black, .font: font])
```

Or omitting it from the attributed string and use the label's default font:

```
label.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: 20)
let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Text.", attributes: [.foregroundColor: UIColor.black])
```